# Learning C++. Using Primer book

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the exercise 1.20

It says to download this header file Sales_item.h

```
/***********************************************************
 *  filename: sales_item.h
 **********************************************************/
#ifndef __SALES_ITEM_H__
#define __SALES_ITEM_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
//using std::istream; using std::ostream;

class Sales_item
{
    /* operations on sales_item object */
public:

    double avg_price(void) const;

    bool same_isbn(const Sales_item &rhs) const /* inline function  */
    {
        return isbn == rhs.isbn;    /* return this->isbn == rhs.isbn*/
    }

    std::istream &read_item(std::istream &in);
    std::ostream &write_item(std::ostream &out) const;

    //      bool add_item(const sales_item &rhs);
    Sales_item add_item(const Sales_item &other);
    /* default constructor --- constructor without parameters       */
    /* default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type    */
    Sales_item(): units_sold(0), revenue(0.0) {}

    /* private members as before       */
private:
    std::string isbn;       /* ISBN                 */
    unsigned units_sold;        /* the number of book sold      */
    double revenue;         /* the total revenue from that book */
};

#if 0
inline
double sales_item::avg_price(void) const
{
    if (units_sold)
        return (revenue / units_sold);  /* return (this->revenue / this->units_sold);   */

    else
        return 0;
}
#endif

inline
double Sales_item::avg_price(void) const
{
    using std::runtime_error;

    try
    {
        if (units_sold == 0)
            throw runtime_error("when units_sold equal 0, error...");

        return (revenue / units_sold);  /* return (this->revenue / this->units_sold);   */
    }

    catch   (runtime_error err)
    {
        std::cout << err.what() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

#endif  /* __SALES_ITEM_H__ */
```

and then to use it with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Sales_item book;
    int gne;
    // read ISBN, number of copies sold, and sales price
    std::cin >> book;
    // write ISBN, number of copies sold, total revenue, and average price
    std::cout << book << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm receiving errors at the std::cin and std::cout lines. Both the errors are:

Invalid operands to binary expression ('istream' (aka 'basic_istream') and 'Sales_item')

I'm using Xcode 5.0.
What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class does not overload `operator <<` and `operator >>` so you are not able to use it with `cout <<` and `cin >>`.  Your class does have

```
std::istream &read_item(std::istream &in);
std::ostream &write_item(std::ostream &out) const;
```

Which you can use like

```
Sales_item book;
int gne;
// read ISBN, number of copies sold, and sales price
book.read_item(std::cin);
// write ISBN, number of copies sold, total revenue, and average price
book.write_item(std::cout);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator<< and no operator>> defined for your type Sales_item, so the compiler doesn't know what to do with the statement "cin >> book" and "cout << book".
You have to write operator overload functions for basic_istream and basic_ostream and Sales_item.

For your case:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sales_item& item)
{
   return item.write_item(os);
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Sales_item& item)
{
   return item.read_item(is);
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza you are right.  I thought he accessed private data.